# Помогите написать регулярное выражения для проверки корректности ввода

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Необходимо написать регулярное выражение для проверки правильности ввода данных.
Строка вида: 1,2,3-10,Po12,Po15-Po20

Числа могут быть любыми, Po может быть с маленькой буквы, Po15-20 либо Po15-Po20
Валидные строки:

```
12
Po12-Po32,1,5,34-56,34-76,45
12-15
1,2
Po12-15,3,4,34-56
```

Я написал регулярку, но не могу понять, как мне учесть запятые и сделать так, чтобы в конце строки запятая не присутствовала: `(?:[Pp]o)?\d{1,2}(-(?:[Pp]o)?\d{1,2})?`

Логика моя такая: первое выражение до запятой может повторяться n раз, разделяться запятыми, в конце запятой нет.

Comment: Мне видится 2 варианта. Изображу схематично: `<выражение>(,<то_же_выражение>)*` или `(<выражение>(,|$))+`.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/vMBeGN/1- посмотрите такое выражение, может быть подойдет. `^(?:(?:(?:[Pp]o)?(?:\d+[,-])+){1,2})?\d+$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

for s in """
12
Po12-Po32,1,5,34-56,34-76,45
12-15
1,2
Po12-15,3,4,34-56
Z45
Po11+12
""".strip().splitlines():
    print(s, "=>", bool(re.fullmatch(r"^(([Pp]o)?\d{1,2}(-(\2)?\d{1,2})?(,(?!$)|$))+", s)))
```

```
12 => True
Po12-Po32,1,5,34-56,34-76,45 => True
12-15 => True
1,2 => True
Po12-15,3,4,34-56 => True
Z45 => False
Po11+12 => False
```

Comment: Круто! 
Можете немножко раскрыть как оно работает? (\2)?  ?(,(?!$)|$))  вот эти места в частности.

Comment: @VladimirFomin `\2` - это ссылка на группу 2, т.е. на `([Pp]o)` (в общем ожидает то же, что и там). `$` - это маркер конца строки. `(?!$)` - это негативный просмотр вперёд (в данном случае впереди не конец строки). Отсюда выражение `(,(?!$)|$))` соответствует запятой и за ней нет конца строки, или просто концу строки (без запятой).

Comment: что-то не получается у меня.   [a-z]+(,(?!$|$)) how,can,use,comma,serarated   Что не так?

Comment: @VladimirFomin Скобочки не там. Надо так - `[a-z]+(,(?!$)|$)`.